# Query result as column name in nested query

Tags: google-bigquery

Problem: BigQuery interpret row value as string instead of column name.

I have a two tables:

```
table_1
| ColumnA  | ColumnB  | ColumnC  |
| 123      | 345      | ColumnD  |
| 678      | 900      | ColumnE  |


table_2
| ColumnD | ColumnE | ColumnF |
| nn      | xx      | 123     |
| kk      | yy      | 678     |
```

What I now want to do is to combine the two tables and select values from a column in table_2 based on the row from table_1.

Something like this:

```
SELECT 
   (SELCT ColumnC FROM table_2 WHERE ColumnF = table_1.ColumnA ) 
FROM table_1
```

The problem is that BigQuery interpret ColumnC as String. So instead of getting the values from ColumnD and ColumnE it just output 'ColumnC'

Comment: I don't even know if this is possible without dynamic SQL, which Big Query might not even support, but I would say you have really bad table design.  If you want to represent a relationship between two tables, you typically do this by setting up join columns.  That is, a value in some column in `table_1` points to a value in another column in `table_2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

> Option 1 - you know column names in table_2 in advance and there are not so many of them so you can check them in the query one by one as below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT a.*,
  CASE 
    WHEN ColumnC = 'ColumnD' THEN ColumnD
    WHEN ColumnC = 'ColumnE' THEN ColumnE   
  END value
FROM `project.dataset.table_1` a
LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.table_2` b
ON ColumnF = ColumnA
```

if to apply to dummy data from your question  - it will give you below result

```
Row ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC value    
1   123     345     ColumnD nn   
2   678     900     ColumnE yy
```

> Option 2 - dynamic evaluation of columns, assuming that layout is simple as in your example in question, but allows to run query without worry of how many possible columns in table_2 and you don't even need to know their names (of course except columnF as it is JOIN key)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT a.*,
  (SELECT SPLIT(x,':')[OFFSET(1)]
    FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(TO_JSON_STRING(b), r'[{}"]', ''))) x
    WHERE SPLIT(x,':')[OFFSET(0)] = ColumnC
  ) value
FROM `project.dataset.table_1` a
LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.table_2` b
ON ColumnF = ColumnA
```

this query will return exactly same result as in option 1

```
Row ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC value    
1   123     345     ColumnD nn   
2   678     900     ColumnE yy
```

Comment: Option 2 was just what I was looking for. Tricky one, thanks!

Comment: consider voting up the question if it helped  - which looks like it did :o)